# MatLab - Horner's algorithm

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I am having some trouble translating a pseudocode for Horner's algorithm into a proper code in MatLab.  I think my confusion stems from the fact that the code assumes that the first vector entry can be referred to by 0, whereas in MatLab, this has to be 1.  I have tried to modify my code accordingly, but I don't get it to work properly.  The pseducode is as follows:

```
input n, (a_i, : 0 ≤ i ≤ n), z_0
   for k = 0 to n-1 do
      for j = n-1 to k step -1 do
          a_j = a_j + z_0*a_(j+1)
      end do
end do
output (a_i: 0 ≤ i ≤ n)
```

Here is my attempt at writing this in MatLab, where `a` is an input vector representing coefficients in a polynomial:

```
function x = horner(a,z_0)
n = length(a);
for k = 1:n-1
    for j = n-1:-1:k
        a(j) = a(j) + (z_0)*a(j+1);
    end
end
x = a;
```

I tried this on the vector `a = [1 -4 7 -5 -2]` which represents coefficients in a polynomial.  I also set `z_0 = 3`.  According to my book, I should have received the output vecor `a = [1 8 25 37 19]`, but my code gives the output vector `a = [-245  -313  -146   -29    -2]`.

If anyone can help me clear up this code, I would be very grateful!

Comment: looks like your looping one to short: I'd say it should be `k = 1:n` and `for j = n:-1:k`

Comment: `edit polyval` shows you how the Matlab people implemented the algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this - here `a` is the vector of polynomial coefficients listed with a(1) as the coefficient of the highest degree term in your polynomial. If your vector is the opposite way round, simply set

```
b = fliplr(a)
```

and call the function using vector `b`. This function will evaluate the polynomial using Horners algorithm. Note that this assumes `z_0` is the value that you want the polynomial evaluated at, hence a single value is returned (not a vector)

```
function x = horner(a,z_0)
n = length(a);
result = a(1);
for j = 2:n
    result = result*z_0 + a(j);
end
x = result;
```

If you want to pass in a vector of values `z` to evaluate so you can evaluate multiple points (the elements of `z`) at the same time, you can pass them in via a vector:

```
function x = horner(a,z)
n = length(a);
m = length(z);
result = a(1)*ones(1,m);
for j = 2:n
    result = result.*z + a(j);
end
x = result;
```

now the returned `x` will be your vector of results

Comment: Great!  Thank you very much for your help.  Had a brainfreeze, and didn't realize that the vector should be flipped :).  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Kristian No problem, note that you can also use the `polyval` function - check out the documentation for it.

Comment: Thanks again.  Yes, I am actually familiar with this function, but since I really want to learn this stuff, I want to be able to write the algorithms myself too :)